# Where to get the client Id for google-cloud-auth?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-signin

## Question

### Where should i get my clientId from for google-auth-library?

- I got these both from the google-services.json but that doesnt work.

  ```
  "oauth_client": [
          {
            "client_id": "THIS DOESNT WORK ",
            "client_type": 1,
            "android_info": {
              "package_name": "com.app",
              "certificate_hash",
            }
          },
          {
            "client_id": "THIS DOESNT WORK AS WELL",
            "client_type": 3
          }
        ],
  ```

## Problem

- I am using react native and the @react-native-google-signin/google-signin package to authenticate users.
- In my react native client code

  ```
  userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
  axois.post("/myApiEndpoint" , { userInfo} );
  ```
- In my server when i run

```
const client = new OAuth2Client(
    "CLIENT_ID"
  );

  const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
    idToken: googleObject.idToken,
    audience: "CLIENT_ID",
  });
```

- I get

```
Uncaught Error Error: Wrong recipient, payload audience != requiredAudience
```

Comment: This is wrong `audience: "CLIENT_ID",`. The audience is typically, in Google Cloud, the URL of the service you are calling or your URL if a client is calling your service. The idToken is decodable (base64 encoded header + payload + signature). Decode the idToken and look at the `aud` key in the payload part.